# Can I Get The Search Phrase From Google?

Tags: php, javascript, html

I want to make several uses of the search phrase that users used in google in order to reach my site.

Is there any programmatic way to do that?

Thanks,
Oran

Comment: http://coding.pressbin.com/59/Get-Google-search-terms-and-rank-from-HTTP-referrer

Comment: Have you even tried anything?

Comment: Sorry. Not yet. Will try and respond soon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `HTTP_REFERER` server variable.

```
$referer= $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
//find the search query from google that brought them here
$qref= strpos($referer,’google’);
if($qref!=”){
$qstart = strpos($referer,’q=’);
$qend = strpos($referer,’&’,$qstart);
$qtext= substr($referer,$qstart+2,$qend-$qstart-2);
$qtext= str_replace(‘+’,’ ‘,$qtext);
}
echo $qtext
```

Taken from [here](http://techexposures.com/2010/02/php-script-show-google-search-that-brought-visitor-to-your-website/).

Comment: It should be noted that `strpos` returns boolean false if the string is not found, and an integer if it is found. So you should use `if($qref !== false){`

Comment: Does this work anymore now that Google transferred over to https and https supposedly doesn't pass HTTP_REFERER data?

Answer (score 5):

You can use the code below:

```
$referrer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']; 
if (!empty($referrer)) { 
    $parts_url = parse_url($referrer); 
    $query = isset($parts_url['query']) ? $parts_url['query'] : ''); 
        if($query) { 
            parse_str($query, $parts_query);             

            $ref_keywords = isset($parts_query['q']) ? $parts_query['q'] : (isset($parts_query['query']) ? $parts_query['query'] : '' )); 
        }
}
```

However, note that Google has now stopped sending the query string in their referrer for all logged in users. So your functionality will work only for users who are logged out of Google . Here is more information on this http://googleblog.blogspot.com/2011/10/making-search-more-secure.html

Comment: Big +1 for mentioning the hiding of queries for logged-in users.

Answer (score 1):

I reckon it should be in the referrer, as the they append the search string to the url via the q-parameter.

Answer (score 1):

You can get it from the ["HTTP_referer"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer) in the request.($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];)

see also [another question regarding the topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1864583/get-original-url-referer-with-php)