# Should Google Analytics utm_ parameters be treated as write-only?

Tags: google-analytics, user-tracking

I have a simple question I can't seem to find a proper answer for.

Does the documentation for Google Analytics specify anywhere whether it's ok or not to use for instance the parameter `utm_term` internally for tracking and customizing a page?

In my mind, the utm_ parameters are write-only and should be used only for tracking and reporting in Google Analytics, and if you need keep track of context on a webpage during a visit (in order to display user related content), you should in addition set your own cookies and/or store session data.

If you think this question is too 'hypothetical', let's just say I'm only asking whether or not Google has expressed any opinion on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are right, the parameters are meant to be write-only and if you want to customise something you should set your own data. You can see this because there are not many *get* methods to use with google analytics:

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/methods/

Comment: Yeah, seems so. I was considering analyzing the _utmz cookie in order to get for instance the utm source parameter server side, but I'm simply not sure if it's reliable.

Comment: What are you trying to do with this?

Comment: Just displaying the logo of a partner if the user came from the partner site.

Comment: You might want to use something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1864583/get-original-url-referer-with-php

Comment: Sure, but in this particular case it is not my decision :-) I asked this question to evaluate the implications of this approach. Thanks for your help.