# Wordpress return original referrer

Tags: php, wordpress, filter, referrer

I've got the following code:

```
add_filter('frm_get_default_value', 'my_custom_default_value_nrt', 10, 2);
function my_custom_default_value_nrt($new_value, $field){
   if(empty($new_value))
  if($field->id == 5859){ //change 5859 to the ID of the field
    $get_url = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']; //stores the value of the referring URL
    $parse = parse_url($get_url); //parses the referring URL
    $new_value = $parse['host']; //stores the domain value of the referring URL
  }
  return $new_value;
}
```

The above code returns the domain of the referring URL of the previous page only. I want to be able to return the original referring domain.

I found the following example that is likely to do what I want, but being a PHP rookie, I'm a bit lost at how to implement it into what I have.

[Get original URL referer with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1864583/get-original-url-referer-with-php)

What's the best way to go about this?

Comment: Is it coming from your own server or another server?

Comment: Another. We have a form that is to grab the referring server domain url.

Comment: Then you can't get the original referer, and if you can, it's because the other servers have decided to pass you onto there. Google and other search engines use special referer-removing code so you can't see what people searched for etc.

Answer (score 0):

The [topic you linked to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1864583/get-original-url-referer-with-php) does exactly what you want. The idea there is to catch HTTP_REFERER value as soon as a new client enters your site first time, and save it in session storage. Session allows to preserve data associated with particular client between page loads. Therefore, original referer string will remain there untouched until you need it later, possibly after many page changes.

Reference: https://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.session.php