# Check from which page the user is coming to the current page in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to check if a user comes from a specific page to the current page.

e.g

```
if (user comes from /bingo.php) 
  { wp_redirect( /newpage.php );exit; }
else { // do nothing };
```

thank you :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1864583/get-original-url-referer-with-php

Comment: @Danijel I don't think that is an exact duplicate, as that question refers to the original referer rather than the previous one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without completely answering your question, I'd say you could look into `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`. This contains the previous page your user came from. Please note that this is not always set.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code for my case:

```
if (!is_user_logged_in() ) {
$icamefrom = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
if ( $icamefrom == 'the_site_you_want_to_check') { wp_redirect( '/signup' ); exit; }; 
}
```