# Get referral Url in new tab

Tags: javascript, referrals, browser-tab

If you click on a link and it opens in a new tab, in that new tab you have some Javascript that gets the referral url but the referral url equals nothing or undefined.

I want to know if it is possible to get the referral url even when the link has been opened in a new tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is doable. In the new tab's JavaScript you can write

```
alert(document.referrer);
```

Know more about [Document Referrer](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_doc_referrer.asp).

You can also do this in PHP. Check this [Get original URL referer with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1864583/get-original-url-referer-with-php)

Comment: sorry you are right i was tesing it through something that must have been a bit weird