# How to run a php script, only if X page redirects you to it

Tags: php, if-statement, reference

```
If (If X Page redirect me here) 
{
run this code
}
else 
{
run this code
}
```

What to write in IF condition? What is the PHP Code?

Comment: What you have tried till yet?

Comment: I am newbie, I do not know the code.

Comment: in your x page html <a href="y.php?from_page=x" >a</a>     and in y page php  if(isset($_GET['from_page']) && $_GET['from_page']=='x'){ echo "run this code "; }else { echo " run this coe "; }

Comment: From you `X` page send some parameters via `GET` or `POST` then in your if section check for the presence of that parameter, if its present then run the code you want, or else code

Comment: [check referer with php](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1864583/6521116)

Answer (score 1):

Try [$_SERVER](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) variable

```
<?php
echo '<pre>';
print_r($_SERVER);
?>
```

Output (on [phpfiddle.org](http://phpfiddle.org/))

```
Array
(
    [DOCUMENT_ROOT] => /home/xfiddlec/public_html/main
    [EE_HOST] => main.xfiddle.com
    [EE_LIB] => /home/xfiddlec/public_html/main/inclibs/
    [EE_LIB_PREFIX] => /home/xfiddlec/public_html/main/inclibs/
    [EE_ROOT] => /home/xfiddlec/public_html/main/
    [GATEWAY_INTERFACE] => CGI/1.1
    [HTTP_ACCEPT] => text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
    [HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE] => en-US,en;q=0.5
    [HTTP_CONNECTION] => close
    [HTTP_HOST] => main.xfiddle.com
    [HTTP_REFERER] => http://phpfiddle.org/
    [HTTP_UPGRADE_INSECURE_REQUESTS] => 1
    [HTTP_USER_AGENT] => Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0
    [HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR] => 157.49.9.71
    [HTTP_X_REAL_IP] => 157.49.9.71
    [PATH] => /bin:/usr/bin
    [PHPRC] => /home/xfiddlec/config
    [PROXY_ADDR] => 31.22.4.102
    [QUERY_STRING] => 
    [REDIRECT_STATUS] => 200
    [REMOTE_ADDR] => 157.49.9.71
    [REMOTE_PORT] => 56471
    [REQUEST_METHOD] => GET
    [REQUEST_URI] => /code_45646358.php
    [SCRIPT_FILENAME] => /home/xfiddlec/public_html/main/code_45646358.php
    [SCRIPT_NAME] => /code_45646358.php
    [SERVER_ADDR] => 31.22.4.102
    [SERVER_ADMIN] => webmaster@www.main.xfiddle.com
    [SERVER_NAME] => main.xfiddle.com
    [SERVER_PORT] => 80
    [SERVER_PROTOCOL] => HTTP/1.0
    [SERVER_SIGNATURE] => 
Apache Server at main.xfiddle.com Port 80


    [SERVER_SOFTWARE] => Apache
    [SITE_WEBMASTER] => PhpFiddle Webmaster
    [SITE_WEBMASTER_URI] => mailto:webmaster@xfiddle.com
    [TZ] => America/New_York
    [UNIQUE_ID] => WRaD3x8WBGYADWv4OMgAAAAN
    [PHP_SELF] => /code_45646358.php
    [REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT] => 1494647775.2
    [REQUEST_TIME] => 1494647775
    [argv] => Array
        (
        )

    [argc] => 0
)
```

You can use following value in if condition

```
if ( $_SERVER[HTTP_REFERER] == "some thing" ) {

    // do my job
} else {
    // do another job

}
```

Or You can pass some GET/POST parameters and check their existence in php page.

Answer (score 0):

**In your X page**

If you navigating using anchor *html*

`<a href="y.php?from_page=x" >y page</a>`

(or)
If your redirecting using *php* *header()*

```
header('Location:y.php?from_page=x');
```

**In Y page**

*php*

```
if(isset($_GET['from_page']) && $_GET['from_page']=='x')
{ 
  echo "run this code "; 
}
else 
{ 
   echo " run this coe ";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] to get the request referer. Refer to this post for get [referer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1864587/6521116).

```
if ($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] = "X page path") 
{
  //run this code
}
else 
{
  //run this code
}
```